# Google OAuth One Time and save access token for future use(long live access token)

Tags: javascript, google-oauth, access-token

I'm working on project in which i used Google analytic API for core reporting based on **`JAVASCRIPT`**. User logging in and after accept application Authentication permission Google analytic code works fine. But when user logged out from google.com or any google's related site like

> ***google+***, ***drive.google.com***, ***www.google.com/analytics***

and again come back to my application it requires login. Is their any solution to save user access token in cookie and if user logged out from any google references websites and my application uses its stored long-live access token so no login required again again.

> for reference check that link.
>   https://oauth2-login-demo.appspot.com/profile

I googled out my question and during this i also check that Google access token default time is **60 minutes**(1 hour). I need long-live user access token so no login required again and again. it  frustrated to users.

Comment: Have you solved your problem? I have same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's late, but for someone coming across this. If you're using PHP and the Google PHP Client, then you need to set the access type as offline when authenticating the user:

`$client->setAccessType("offline");`

This would cause Google to send back a refresh token which you store for the user.

You'd then use this refresh token to get a new access token every time the old access token has expired:

`$acess_token = $client->fetchAccessTokenWithRefreshToken($refresh_token);`

In the check above I didn't add any conditional to see if the old access token has indeed expired. But the above returns an array, and if you inspect it, you'll see that it has a key called "created". Google seems to leave access tokens valid for 1 hour, so you'd do a check against the old created time to see if it's been almost one hour since that time, and then run the `fetchAccessTokenWithRefreshToken()` method.

Alternately you can use `$client->isAccessTokenExpired()`;

You can read more about this here: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/web-server#offline (has examples for other languages)

Update:

There are times the refresh token wouldn't be sent just because you made the access type "offline". You'd have to set another property in addition to `$client->setAccessType("offline");` always be sure to get back the refresh token

So you'd do:

```
$client->setAccessType("offline");
$client->setApprovalPrompt('force');
```

To always get the refresh token each time a user authenticates their account.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you want to keep users logged in even if they logged out of Google, then you have only one option, you have to roll your own session management. You can get a long lived token, a refresh token, but definitely don't save it in a cookie, save it in a database.

Comment: how to get a long-lived token and refresh token!!! as you see stackoverflow also using the same scenario that i want. when login with google in stackover flow it store google oauth cookie in session.